# cross compile glibc for Android ARM - configure error

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, cross-compiling, glibc

I am trying to cross-compile **glibc** (version 2.28) for ARM (because the **libc.a** distributed with Android NDK lacks the `xdr_()` routines I need) and I am hitting an issue in the configure.

This is my configure:

```
../glibc-2.28/configure --prefix=/home/me/TEST --host=arm-linux-androideabi --disable-multilib
```

The error output by configure is:

> GNU libc requires kernel header files from Linux 3.2.0 or later to be
>   installed before configuring.

It is defaulting to kernel headers in `/usr/include/linux`. I know I can change where it looks for kernel header files with `--with-headers`, but don't know where to point this to? I tried `apt-get upgrade` (and `update`) but still get the same configure error.

**Note 1:**

I have already built my **arm-linux-androideabi-()** binaries successfully and have built other packages OK. I am running on a Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 system.

**Note 2:**

I checked stackoverflow for similar questions and found one, very similar, but the suggestion was to replace `--host` with `--target`. However, the responder was mistaken in thinking that the `--host` argument defines the machine on which the code is being compiled.